# Does "tradition" here mean beliefs or customs?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

"But well-established tradition, and difference of physiognomy, prove conclusively that not all the present inhabitants of the mountains are the original inhabitants of that region"

Does tradition mean beliefs or customs? The Oxford Learners' Dictionary website defines tradition as a belief, custom or way of doing something that has existed for a long time among a particular group of people; [or] a set of these beliefs or customs

Comment: Beliefs, customs, any or all elements of culture.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence it would be in the sense of the knowledge handed down from previous times.

[tradition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464209/does-tradition-here-mean-beliefs-or-customs)

> 1.the handing down of statements, beliefs, legends, customs, information, etc., from generation to generation, especially by word
>   of mouth or by practice: a story that has come down to us by popular
>   tradition.
>   2. something that is handed down: the traditions of the Eskimos.